How can I reduce the space between navigation bar and a title?
This is my template for blog posts. When the window you are viewing the post in is maximized, the spacing between nav and post-title is far too much. I want to reduce the space and keep it consistent.


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Cambria', serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a {
  color: #555;
  margin: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.post-title {
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.post-date {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #888;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.post-content {
  text-align: left;
}

.post-content h2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #444;
}

.post-content p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

footer {
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <a href="button1.html">Button 1</a>
    <a href="button2.html">Button 2</a>
    <a href="button3.html">Button 3</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="post-title">Title</div>
      <div class="post-date">Date</div>
      <div class="post-content">
        <p><em>Subheader</em></p>

        <h2>Subheading 1</h2>
        <p>Content</p>

        <h2>Subheading 2</h2>
        <p>Content</p>

        <h2>Conclusion</h2>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>



I have tried reducing padding-top and removing justify-content, but it seems like the title just will not change much at all when the window is maximized. It stays the same.

Instead of using <div class="post-title">Title</div> for  the title, you should be using <h1>.

I commented out the styles that cause this problem.

Remove justify-content: center from .content. Since .content takes over the entire available height, assigning this will makes its child .container centered vertically, which causes the margin being too large on full page.

Remove margin: auto from .container. This also causes itself been centered both vertically and horizontally. Since you already have align-items: center on its parent, using margin to center it horizontally is redundant. Also, you don't want to center it vertically, so removing this rule fixes this problem.




html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Cambria', serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  /* margin: auto; */
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a {
  color: #555;
  margin: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.post-title {
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.post-date {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #888;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.post-content {
  text-align: left;
}

.post-content h2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #444;
}

.post-content p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

footer {
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <a href="button1.html">Button 1</a>
    <a href="button2.html">Button 2</a>
    <a href="button3.html">Button 3</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="post-title">Title</div>
      <div class="post-date">Date</div>
      <div class="post-content">
        <p><em>Subheader</em></p>

        <h2>Subheading 1</h2>
        <p>Content</p>

        <h2>Subheading 2</h2>
        <p>Content</p>

        <h2>Conclusion</h2>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>



